# Array showing only one row from json file

Tags: json, codeigniter-3

Here is my CONTROLLER

```
public function showCategoryJson(){
    $this->load->model('user/category_model');
    $data[] = $this->category_model->displayCategory();

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My MODEL

```
function displayCategory(){
  $query = $this->db->get('categories');
  $res = $query->result_array();
  return $res;
}
```

and my VIEW

```
<?php
  $url = site_url('user/category/showCategoryJson'); // path to your JSON file
  $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
  // echo $data;
  $results = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

  foreach ($results as $key => $cat) { 
?>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
 <td><?php echo $cat[$key]->categoryname; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $cat[$key]->username; ?></td>
 <td class="center"><a class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit"></a> <a class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash delete" id="<?php echo $cat[$key]->categoryid; ?>"></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I have tried all the ways to get all the value of that array (from JSON). But i get only one row. here is the screenshot-
[image: Screenshot of result i get]

Here is the json result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways that you can start "debugging" is by actually printing out the contents of $results.
Try the following before the foreach loop:

```
print_r($results);
```

The results will show something similar to this:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [categoryid] => 10 [categoryname] => sdf [username] => icicle ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [categoryid] => 12 [categoryname] => ase [username] => icicle ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [categoryid] => 23 [categoryname] => aser [username] => icicle ) ) ) sdf icicle

This means that the json contents have been decoded into a nested array.

You could try adding the "true" parameter for the json_decode function and accessing the variables as an array instead.

> $results = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON feed

Full code:

```
    <?php
        $url = site_url('user/category/showCategoryJson'); // path to your JSON file
        $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
        $results = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON feed
        foreach ($results[0] as $key => $cat) { 
    ?>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php echo $cat['categoryname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cat['username']; ?></td>   
    <td class="center"><a class="btn btn-success fa fa-edit"></a> <a class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash delete" id="<?php echo $cat['categoryid']; ?>"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Edit: To pass data from the controller to the view, you can assign the result from your model to a variable and then instruct the controller to load a view, along with the variable that you've stored the data in.

For example, in your controller, you could change the following:

```
public function showCategoryJson(){
    $this->load->model('user/category_model');
    $data['category_data'] = $this->category_model->displayCategory();
    $url = site_url('user/category/showCategoryJson'); // path to your JSON file
    $json_data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $data['results'] = json_decode($json_data,true); // decode the JSON feed
    $this->load->view('[YOUR_VIEW_NAME]',$data);
}
```

You can then use $category_data and $results in the view.

Comment: one question (just want to learn, if you don't mind) if i used in controller 
$data['res'] = $this->category_model->displayCategory();
then what i have to change in my view?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how you can pass your data from the controller to the view. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks brother... I will try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
json_decode($data,true);
```

When **TRUE**, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.